# How to strip the index action part from link_to in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

When I use:

```
link_to "Title", {:controller => 'my', :id=>1, :param=>2}
```

It produces:

```
<a href="/my/index?id=1&param=2">
```

But I want the following:

```
<a href="/my?id=1&param=2">
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

**I use Rails 3.1.0**

Comment: Please specify Rails version, as routing works quote differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is best to use named routes, that you can later call as methods.
Example:

In routes.rb:

```
match '/my/:id/:param' => 'my#index', :as => :my
```

In a view:

```
link_to 'anchor', my_url(:id => 2, :param => 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other than `Achilles` answer You can also give string parameter to link_to function

```
<%= link_to "Title", "/my/index?id=1&param=2" %>
```

You can also give string parameter to link_to function

```
<% id, param = 1,2 %>
<%= link_to "Title", "/my/index?id=#{id}&param=#{param}" %>
```